# Increasing speed of Timer in Java

Tags: java, timer, actionlistener, increment, repaint

I'm making a game with Java and I'm currently using Timers for all my animations and game controls. But I'm having trouble choosing the right way to increase the speed of a Timer. My game is supposed to get faster and faster as the game progresses, and I'm finding that there are many ways to increase the speed of my objects, but I'm not sure which one is the most efficient to use.

For example, let's say the int `xpos` is the variable the increments the xposition of an object.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener()  //01
{                                                  //02
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)     //03
    {                                              //04
        xpos++;                                    //05
        repaint();                                 //06
    }                                              //07
}                                                  //08
                                                   //09
timer.start();                                     //10
```

To increase the speed of this, I could increase the incrementation of xpos on line 5 to `xpos+=2`.

I could also increase the speed by decreasing the millisecond parameter for the Timer to: `Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener()` on line 1.

Or I could add a second Timer that would do the same task to double the speed of the timer. Basically, I could do this:

```
Mover mover = new Mover();
Timer timer = new Timer(100, mover);        
Timer timer2 = new Timer(100, mover);
timer.start();
timer2.start();

class Mover implements ActionListener
{                                                  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)     
    {                                              
        xpos++;                                    
        repaint();                                 
    }                                              
}
```

Which one do you think would be most effective? Or should I combine all these techniques? Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Go with the first technique.  Don't stuff with the `Timer` instances, just have them go at a normal, fixed frame rate.

Comment: +1 for adding line numbers to the first bit of your code. I think that should either be incorporated in SO code formatting or just be a required practice.

Comment: In your last question you said that the more you increase the y interval the more flickering you get, so that would seem to imply you decrease the Timer interval.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I think I'm gonna experiment with incrementing my xpos variable more and decreasing the Timer interval. Because right now, I'm using a lot of Timer instances, and it's messing with my game in many ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Keep the Timer beat steady, invariant.
- Store your logical position and velocity with doubles or Point2D.Double.
- Don't rely on the accuracy of the timer interval.
- Calculate change in position based on velocity and change in system time.